# SSIS lookup with numeric value not working

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am new to using ssis and am on my third package.  We are taking data from Oracle into Sql Server.  On my oracle table, the unique key is called recnum and is numeric(12,0).  In this particular package, I am trying to take the record from oracle, lookup in a sql server table to see if that unique key is found, and if not add the record to the sql server table.  My issue is it wouldn't find a match.  After much testing, I came up with the following method that works.  But I don't understand why I had to do this.

How I currently have it working:
I get the data from oracle.  In my next step, I added a derived column that uses the oracle column.  (The expression is just that field, no other formatting.)  Then in the lookup I use the derived column instead of the column from Oracle.

We had already done this on another table where the unique key was numeric(8,0) and it worked ok without needing a derived column.

Comment: What is the data column data type in you SQL Server table?

Comment: I made it Numeric(12,0)  I originally made it too big, and thought that may be the issue.  So I corrected it.  But still the same issue

Comment: Sounds strange. Try to compare values in SSMS. Create an Linked Server object to your Oracle box then `INNER JOIN` your SQL Server table to `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Oracle_Linked_Server_Name, 'SELECT * FROM source_table')`.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is very fussy about data types, lookups only work nicely if data types match.

Double click on the Data Path lines between Data Flow objects to check data types. I use Data Conversion tasks or CAST statements to force matching data types when I use lookups.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pulled all my hair out til I read this, went back and looked, and noticed one column was decimal(9,3) and the other was decimal(10,3). Changed them to match types and everything works. Now I'm bald but at least the SSIS package is working.